# SQL Server Integration Services Login Failure

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, windows-server-2008

I noticed an error in my event log today that states:

> The SQL Server Integration Services 10.0 service failed to start due
>   to the following error:  The service did not start due to a logon
>   failure.

The service is configured to use ./sqluser but I cannot find this login with the domain.

What exactly is this services used for?  What login should I be using for this service and what rights/privileges does the user need for this service to function properly.  I am using SQL 2008 under Windows Server 2008 r2.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What exactly is this services used for

[Managing Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137731.aspx)

> Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services includes the Integration
>   Services service, a Windows service for managing Integration Services
>   packages. The Integration Services service is available only in SQL
>   Server Management Studio.
>
> Running the Integration Services service provides the following
>   management capabilities:
>
> Starting remote and locally stored packages
>
> Stopping remote and locally running packages
>
> Monitoring remote and locally running packages
>
> Importing and exporting packages
>
> Managing package storage
>
> Customizing storage folders
>
> Stopping running packages when the service is stopped
>
> Viewing the Windows Event log
>
> Connecting to multiple Integration Services servers
>
> The Integration Services service is installed when you install the
>   Integration Services component of SQL Server. By default, the
>   Integration Services service is started and the startup type of the
>   service is set to automatic. The service must be running to monitor
>   the packages that are stored in the SSIS Package Store. The SSIS
>   Package Store can be either the msdb database in an instance of SQL
>   Server or the designated folders in the file system.
>
> The Integration Services service is not required if you only want to
>   design and execute Integration Services packages. However, the service
>   is required to list and monitor packages using SQL Server Management
>   Studio.

- What login should I be using for this service and what rights/privileges

[Managing the Integration Services Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140100.aspx)

> By default, the Integration Services service runs in the context of
>   the NETWORK SERVICE account.

I have not found a simplified list of what is required for the service to run correctly but this article describes how to connect to a [remote SSIS service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337083.aspx).

I'll keep browsing MSDN articles